# No agrega elemento seleccionado de un cuadro de lista

Tags: html, jquery, select

Se tienen dos cuadros de lista, uno con plantillas a escoger y otro con plantillas a facturar. Con un botón se trata de agregar al segundo cuadro de lista la opción seleccionada del primero, pero no hace nada.

```
<br><br>
    <div id="seleccionar">
        <select name="seleccionarPlantilla" id="seleccionarPlantilla">
            <option value="option1">Tom</option>
            <option value="option2">Logros</option>
            <option value="option3">Líderes</option>
            <option value="option4">Marca</option>   
            <option value="option5">Comida</option>
            <option value="option6">Abogacía</option>
            <option value="option7">Nuestro</option>
            <option value="option8">Vigas</option>  
            <option value="option9">Axis</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="botonSeleccionar">
        <button id="Agregar" name="Agregar" onclick="">Agregar</button>
    </div>

        <br><br>
    <select name="plantillasAFacturar" id="plantillasAFacturar">        
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function agregarPlantilla(){
        $(plantillasAFacturar).prepend($( "#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected" ).attr("value"));
     }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantos, errores. Empezando porque $(plantillasafacturar), debería ser $('#plantillasafacturar'). Así es como conviertes tu selector en un objeto jquery.
Además, nunca llamas a tu función mediante un evento. Yo intuyo que lo quieres hacer en el evento del click del botón agregar, y esa es la solución que te doy. También podrías hacerlo en el 'onchange'

Aqui está el codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZprmd?editors=1111

Y aqui el HTML

```
<div id="seleccionar">
        <select name="seleccionarPlantilla" id="seleccionarPlantilla">
            <option value="option1">Tom</option>
            <option value="option2">Logros</option>
            <option value="option3">Líderes</option>
            <option value="option4">Marca</option>   
            <option value="option5">Comida</option>
            <option value="option6">Abogacía</option>
            <option value="option7">Nuestro</option>
            <option value="option8">Vigas</option>  
            <option value="option9">Axis</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="botonSeleccionar">
        <button type="submit" id="agregar" name="agregar">Agregar</button>
    </div>

        <br><br>
    <select name="plantillasAFacturar" id="plantillasAFacturar">        
    </select>
```

y el JS

```
// siempre cashea los objetos en una variable para que la performance sea mejor
var $agregar = $('#agregar'),
    $select2 = $('#plantillasAFacturar');
// Debes agregar el event handler
$agregar.on('click', function() {
  var seleccion = $('#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected').attr('value');
  $select2.prepend('<option value="'+ seleccion +'">' + seleccion + '</option>');
});
```

Por cierto, si quieres que agregue la etiqueta y no el valor, te convendría usar este snippet (yo te puse el valor, porque así sugerías tú que querías hacerlo.
Además puedes optimizarlo poniendo un valor por defecto al segundo select.

// siempre cashea los objetos en una variable para que la performance sea mejor

```
var $agregar = $('#agregar'),
    $select2 = $('#plantillasAFacturar');
// Debes agregar el event handler
$agregar.on('click', function() {
  var seleccion = $('#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected').attr('value'),
      etiqueta = $('#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected').text();
  $select2.prepend('<option value="'+ seleccion +'">' + etiqueta + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: En [es.so] tenemos un snippet de jsfiddle para poder ejecutar código HTML+CSS+JS. Puedes tener tu ejemplo funcionando aquí sin tener que poner un enlace externo a codepen o cualquier otra herramienta similar. Es el boton con los simbolos `<>` en el editor, al lado de insertar imagen.

Comment: Gracias! Lo tendré en cuenta en mi próxima respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas, si ya quieres que no se repitan las option agregadas, deberías hacer una búsqueda en el otro select antes de agregar los datos.

IMPORTANTE: En tu botón, en el `onclick` no tenías nada escrito, debes llamar a la función javascript/jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     function agregarPlantilla(){
     $('#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected').each(function () {
        $("<option/>").
        val($(this).val()).
        text($(this).text()).
        appendTo("#plantillasAFacturar");
    });
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
    <div id="seleccionar">
        <select name="seleccionarPlantilla" id="seleccionarPlantilla">
            <option value="option1">Tom</option>
            <option value="option2">Logros</option>
            <option value="option3">Líderes</option>
            <option value="option4">Marca</option>   
            <option value="option5">Comida</option>
            <option value="option6">Abogacía</option>
            <option value="option7">Nuestro</option>
            <option value="option8">Vigas</option>  
            <option value="option9">Axis</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <br><br>
    <div id="botonSeleccionar">
        <button id="Agregar" name="Agregar" onclick="agregarPlantilla()">Agregar</button>
    </div>
    
    <br><br>
    <select name="plantillasAFacturar" id="plantillasAFacturar">        
    </select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes unos cuantos fallos de concepto. Publico tu código con los arreglillos para que funcione y seguidamente te voy comentando en lo que estabas fallando.

**HTML**

```
div id="seleccionar">
        <select name="seleccionarPlantilla" id="seleccionarPlantilla">
            <option value="option1">Tom</option>
            <option value="option2">Logros</option>
            <option value="option3">Líderes</option>
            <option value="option4">Marca</option>   
            <option value="option5">Comida</option>
            <option value="option6">Abogacía</option>
            <option value="option7">Nuestro</option>
            <option value="option8">Vigas</option>  
            <option value="option9">Axis</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="botonSeleccionar">
        <button id="agregar" name="Agregar">Agregar</button>
    </div>

        <br><br>
    <select name="plantillasAFacturar" id="plantillasAFacturar">        
    </select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#agregar').click(function () {
    $('#plantillasAFacturar').append($("#seleccionarPlantilla option:selected"));
});
```

**1)** Para empezar, lo primero que he hecho ha sido cambiar la declaración de la función a una anónima sobre el elemento de botón "agregar" al que le he cambiado el nombre (tenía el nombre de "Agregar" y no me gusta empezar los nombres de otra cosa que no seas de una **clase** son mayúsculas.

**2)** Luego he cambiado el selector que estabas usando en tu función de **Jquery**, de la manera que lo estabas llamando hacías alusión a una variable `$(plantillasAFacturar)` en vez de a un elemento llamado por su **ID** `$('#plantillasAFacturar')`.

**3)** Y por último, he cambiado la función de **prepend** por **append**, para que el elemento añadido se posicione el último en la lista de **option** (con **prepend** se posicionaría el primero de la lista).